# Laying ot components in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, formatting, layout-manager

Oh hay there, didn't see you. I was wondering if there is a better, more efficient way of formatting the labels, panels, and buttons in java then what I have done below. Here is my code, I want to make Welcome, the date, and the button to all be on separate lines. And the only logical way of doing so is creating blank labels, right?

```
private void GeneralTab() {
  generalPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
  String currentTime = SimpleDateFormat.getInstance().format(
    Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel("WELCOME "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" ")); 
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel("                  "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel("Today's Date: " + currentTime));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
  generalPanel.add(new JLabel(" "));
   generalPanel.add(createExitButton());
 }
```

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions regarding my answer.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you need to learn some more about [`LayoutManagers`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/LayoutManager.html).  They help you layout components in different ways.

Check out the Java tutorials.  They are probably the best way to get started using different layouts.

Here is a link to the tutorial:

> http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

In your case, it looks like you want to use a `BoxLayout`.  You should place the components you want on one line in their own `JPanel`.  Then, add each `JPanel` to the `generalPanel`.  You need to set the layout manager of the `generalPanel` to a `BoxLayout` like so:

```
generalPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(generalPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Comment: I still can get used to the `oracle.com` links for java docs and tutorials... :)

Comment: @Lipis, haha, I know.  Every time I'm about to click on one I hesitate a little bit.

Comment: @qmega, yeah, I said that all the components that should be on one line need one JPanel.